# Change background color first/last row of list view

Tags: android, listview

I fill list view with this code

```
public class FillList extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    List<Map<String, String>> prolist = new ArrayList<Map<String, String>>();

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String r) {

        String[] from = {"D", "C", "B","A"};
        int[] views = { R.id.lblPrice,R.id.lblAmount,R.id.lblDescription,R.id.lblDate};
        final SimpleAdapter ADA = new SimpleAdapter(Products.this,
                prolist, R.layout.lsttemplate, from,
                views);
        listview.setAdapter(ADA);

    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

          Map<String, String> datanum = new HashMap<String, String>();

          datanum.put("D", "price");
          datanum.put("C", "amount");
          datanum.put("B", "description");
          datanum.put("A", "date");
          prolist.add(datanum);

          while (rs.next()) {
              datanum = new HashMap<String, String>();


              datanum.put("D", rs.getString("Bes"));
              datanum.put("C", rs.getString("Bed"));
              datanum.put("B", rs.getString("Sharh"));
              datanum.put("A", rs.getString("Date"));
              prolist.add(datanum);

          }
    }               
}
```

I change background color of first row `ListView` with this code

```
listview.getChildAt(0).setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#7092bf"));
```

Now all thing is ok and first row changed background color

but,

When i scroll down on `ListView` some other row of `ListView` also changed background color.

I want only only only change first row of `ListView`.

If i want change background color of last row what should I do?

Comment: This happens because in ListView rows gets reused using viewHolder pattern inOrder to save the memory

Comment: I had the same question and failed because I thought I could use a StateListDrawable making use of state_first (https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/StateListDrawable#attr_android:state_first), state_middle, and state_last.  But these states were always false.  After reading ListView's source code, I don't think StateListDrawable is implemented for them.  I don't understand why not.  Is the solution from Hai the approach the Android platform team recommends?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest you subclass SimpleAdapter and override the getView method:

```
public class MySimpleAdapter extends SimpleAdapter {
  public MySimpleAdapter(Context context, List<? extends Map<String, ?>> data, int resource, String[] from, int[] to) {
    super(context, data, resource, from, to);
  }
  public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {  
    View view = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
    if (position == 0) {
      // set special background for first view
      view.setBackgroundColor(...);
    } else if (position == getCount() - 1) {
      // set special background on last view
      view.setBackgroundColor(...);
    } else {
      // set normal background on other views
      view.setBackgroundColor(...);
    }
    return view;
  }
}
```

What this achieves: this is the method the ListView calls to decide what view to display on screen for a particular item, at a given position. You now have access to that view, so you should modify it here.

Remember to also set the background to normal - when the View scrolls of screen, it will be recycled, meaning it can later be used to display a *different* item in your list, which may or may not be the first one.

To use your new adapter:

```
    final MySimpleAdapter ADA = new MySimpleAdapter(Products.this,
            prolist, R.layout.lsttemplate, from,
            views);
    listview.setAdapter(ADA);
```

Comment: i fill list with this ` listview.setAdapter(ADA);` .i does not know how implement SimpleAdapter.You can complete your code?

Comment: `view.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#7092bf"));` this is correct?still change color first row and when i scroll down changed some other row

Comment: Did you also do view.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE) to set it back in the "else" branch?

Comment: oh yes ok i set else white and all thing correct.thank you very very much

Comment: excuse me another question if i want change background color of last row what should I do؟

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/131731/discussion-between-hai-and-chat-kai).

Comment: Updated answer for handling last item

Answer (score 0):

It is to save memory. The Android OS sends views which are off the screen to somewhere else from the heap or cache. So the views at index 0 changes when you scroll.

To solve this give a tag to first view of list and use the tag to change background color. [findViewWithTagTraversal](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html#findViewWithTagTraversal(java.lang.Object)) will help you